# Loading 2 processes in a dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

Can anyone help ?

I have 2 x sh (bash) scripts.

script 1 outputs constantly to the STDOUT i.e. its blocking.

script 2 calls into a service that script 1 starts.

So if I start script 1 - script 2 never starts, and if i start script 2 then it won't work because script 1 isn't started.

I think I need a way of launching 2 processes in my dockerfile.

Once working, script 1 will continue to run outputing to the STDOUT - i..e continuing blocking

script 2 once run will exit.

In my dockerfile I have this, but I just can't seem to get it to work

```
CMD ["sh","-c","./startme.sh","./additems.sh"]
```

I also tried the

./startup.sh && ./additems.sh - but because startup is blocking then additems never runs.

THe additems (script 2) is short lived, it will run its job and eventually exit, obviously this depends on script1 running (startup).

I thought it was something to do with passing -c to the sh - but nothing seems to work

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

After some help below, I have the following

here is the startup script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

./start-console.sh &
./additems.sh

exec "$@"
```

The 2 x scripts do in fact run in parallel, which is good news, actually the additems even manages to run the thing it needs after a small pause - which I added to allow the first script to finish loading i.e.

```
sleep 15
```

So script1 (start-console) is busy outputting to the STDOUT - everything is working fine

Script2 started at the same time, also good, waits 15 seconds, and runs its command succesfully but then it exits and the whole container exits..

if you notice in the main startup script i have

```
exec "$@"
```

Which I thought was supposed to hold the container open ?

Comment: Usually you’d do this in two separate containers.  If you can get one process to talk to the other through a network connection, this tends to be easier to set up (and monitor and maintain) than trying to stuff two things into one container.

Comment: Why would you want to keep it running after it has finished doing its job?

Comment: Daniu, The script runs 2 processes. the first process must always continue, it does not exit. The second process does exit. BUT when the second process exits then the whole docker container exits - docker ps shows it exited

Comment: Set the `&` after `./additems.sh` and not behind  `start-console.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Create a starter script (starter.sh) like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
./additems.sh &
./startme.sh
```

Give script execution rights:

```
chmod +x starter.sh
```

Insert following entry in Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./starter.sh /
```

And modify the following line:

```
CMD ["sh","-c","./starter.sh"]
```

Comment: Why not just `"sh", "-c", "./first.sh & ./second.sh"`

Comment: Thanks - this kind of works! but once the second script exits the docker container exits.